# Summary for multiple / specific columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a table with multiple columns and instead of running the summary on specific rows e.g. `summary(a)`, `summary(b)` etc. I was wondering if there's a way to do it with a for loop.

In psuedo code, I'd look something like this:

```
list = [a, b, c] #where a,b,c are column names
for i in list:
    print(summary(i))
```

Comment: For rows, `apply(df, 1, summary)`. For columns, just `summary(df)`.

Comment: Subset the columns and then use `summary`, `summary(df[list])`. For eg for `mtcars`, `cols <- c("mpg", "cyl");summary(mtcars[cols])`.

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not sure if this should be another question, but how would you do it for variance, SD etc when the columns have NA values e.g. column `a` has a list of numbers as well as NA values. So individually, you'd write `var(a, na.rm = TRUE)` and you'd get a value, But how do you do this for multiple variables?

Comment: @Shotokan Try `sapply(mtcars[cols], function(x) c(sd(x, na.rm = T), var(x, na.rm = T)))`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks, mate. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ronak stated:

Subset the columns and then use `summary`, `summary(df[list])`. For eg for `mtcars, cols <- c("mpg", "cyl");summary(mtcars[cols])`

Answer (score 1):

Appending to Ronak's answer; if you don't want to create an otherwise unneeded variable, you can subset the desired columns directly in the dataframe for a single-line solution:

```r
summary(mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl")]
```